# How to override angular components generated through node modules

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular-components, sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

I am working on Hybris smartedit and the login page form is generated through node_modules.

On login page load I want set username and password through smartedit custom loader component which is not in node_modules.

What is the correct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never had to do that with components, but you can try to extend your node_modules component in a new component :

```
class ComponentB extends ComponentA {}
```